# Inserting values in tcl database

Tags: tcl

I am having trouble adding content to this database in tcl:

```
  set fd [open country.txt]
  set content [read $fd]
  close $fd
  set qcontent [string map {' ''} $content]
  db eval "INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,2,'$content')"
```

Still is not adding the requested values.

Comment: I assume you're using SQLite here…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db eval "INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,2,'$qcontent')"
```

It should be the qcontent variable to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

You should use braces to avoid having to deal with single quotes:

```
set fd [open country.txt]
set content [read $fd]
close $fd
db eval {INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,2,$content)}
```

And since you didn't need to escape the single quotes, you have less variables and make less mistakes.